# Salesforce removing line breaks when importing data from CSV

Tags: data-loader, import, formatting, outputtext

We're currently busy with a migration of data from our old system to our brand new Salesforce system.
As part of this migration, we're migrating data fields that contain flat text with line breaks, for example:

```
"Function

Description of function 
More text."
```

When exporting this from our old system to a CSV file, these line breaks are still intact: I can open up the CSV file and I still see the line breaks in the corresponding texts in the cell.

After running the Data Loader to import the data to Salesforce, however, all line breaks get removed, resulting in this when inputting our example:

```
"Function Description of function More text."
```

I have looked through the settings of the Data Loader, but I haven't found a way to make sure that the line breaks aren't removed from the data when uploading.

Does anyone know how to tackle this problem? Some of these text fields and their layouts are important for contract creation in our business.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Kind regards,
Martin

Comment: Not sure if this is an answer, but try enabling Bulk API. When the app starts, cancel the default dialog, click on Settings > Settings > Enable Bulk API, OK. This should probably preserve the line breaks correctly. You can also try the Data Import Wizard found in Setup > Data Management > Data Import or Setup > Integrations > Data Import Wizard.

Comment: What's the data type of the target field in Salesforce? I've just tried a test insert and it looks like that for the ``Text`` type line breaks don't work, but for the ``Text Area`` they do.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks, I've tried this, but the data shows no line breaks in Salesforce

Also, weirdly enough, I do see the line breaks when I export the data from Salesforce afterwards. It seems the website just doesn't know how to handle them when displaying the data?

Comment: @PrzemysławTamoń The data field is a Rich Text Area (32768)

Comment: @Fengshen RTA (Rich Text Area) would need HTML line breaks (`<br/>`) in order to show line breaks. This is a feature of HTML. Use normal TA (Text Area) or LTA (Long Text Area) fields to show line breaks as normal.